# How to set content Encoding in HTML file

Tags: html, tomcat, gzip, content-encoding

I want to use GZIP encoding to my site and how should .
I set the **content encoding** of my html file to `gzip`.

T tried like this

```
<html lang="en" pageEncoding="gzip">
```

I am using Apache Tomcat web server.

Comment: Are you using Apache Tomcat or Apache HTTPD?

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

Comment: Is this HTML file an HTML **file** or the HTML output of a script?

Comment: @Quentin
It is html file only

Comment: *i tried like this* — Where did you put that code?

Comment: *Hint:I am using apache web server* — which Apache webserver? Apache HTTPD or Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused content encoding (gzip, deflate) with page (aka character) encoding (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, etc.).

In order to enable gzip compression on Apache Tomcat, you have to do it at the `<Connector>` level -- and only HTTP connectors are supported. See the `compressableMimeType`, `compression`, and `compressionMinSize` attributes for `<Connector>` in the [Apache Tomcat HTTP Connector Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 0):

Content compression is handled by the web server at the HTTP protocol layer.  There are hints you can put in content itself to have the web server do things like this, but it's dependent on your server and the content.  You can configure your web server to compress static content or dynamic content and if you're using something like PHP you can even do compression in your PHP code.